# Basic Perl for homework

Tags: perl

I am in school and in a network programming class. I have no Perl experience at all. Our assignment is as follows.

Write a short program that uses the backticks `` function to run the external command ps -aux to list all currently running processes owned by the user, whose username is given as a command line argument.

Hint:

```
$ARGV[0] or die "without a username given\n";
my $.... = $ARGV[0];
my @ps = `ps -axu`;
foreach my $..... (@ps) {
print $line if …../;
}
```

I have changed the code to this:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;
my $line;

$ARGV[0] or die "without a username given\n";
my $test = $ARGV[0];
my @ps = `ps -axu`;
foreach my $test (@ps) {
print $line if ...../;
}
```

however, i keep getting this error:

syntax error at C:\Perl\W4A2new.pl line 10, near "if ..."
Search pattern not terminated at C:\Perl\W4A2new.pl line 10.

Can anyone help me out??? Please. thank you.

Comment: You have a syntax error on line 10 near "if". Something to do with your regex (search) pattern by the look of it. Try posting your actual code.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;


my $username = $ARGV[0] or die "without a username given\n";
my @ps = `ps -axu $username`;
foreach my $line (@ps) {
   print $line, "\n";
}
```

you must execute this script in this way (assuming the script name is myscript.pl):

```
perl myscript.pl your_operating_system_user_name
```

Comment: I get the message "ERROR: Must set personality to get -x option." - also if I just type "ps -axu $myusername" directly in the shell... on standard ubuntu

Comment: perl myscript.pl your_user_name

Comment: $myusername is not valid, it should be your login username

Comment: I know but I am not going to tell you this one ;-)

Comment: ps --version -> procps version 3.2.8 on recent stable ubuntu (precise)

Comment: I tried this but I keep getting the die "without a username given"  , how do I get it put my username in and print our the current processes running? It is due today.... Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. The `ps` command is usually invoked like `ps aux` (without leading minus).
2. Specifying a user name in the ps argument has no effect I can see
3. Using backticks is convenient, but could be considered bad style.
4. The first column of the `ps aux` output can contain a numeric user ID.
5. We can use `/etc/passwd` to translate between user IDs and user names.

Here is code that prints out all `ps` lines that start with a given string:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings;

print grep /^\Q$ARGV[0]\E/, `ps aux`;
```

That last line could be written verbose:

```
my @temp;
for (`ps aux`) {
  push @temp, $_ if /^\Q$ARGV[0]\E/;
}
print @temp;
```

That script would be invoked like `perl script.pl root` or `perl script.pl 1000`.

Now as I said, we can translate between usernames and user IDs. Also, we can treat the `ps` output as the column data it is. The columns are

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
```

We can access these cols by `my @cols = split ' ', $line, 11`. We have to specify a maximum number of cols as the command may contain whitespaces. If the user contains only digit characters, we translate to the corresponding name in `/etc/passwd`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings;

my $username = $ARGV[0] or die <<"END_USAGE";
USAGE: perl $0 USERNAME
    USERNAME -- the full username you want ps output for.
END_USAGE

my %id_2_name = do {
  open my $passwd, "<", "/etc/passwd" or die "Can't open passwords: $!";
  map { (split /:/)[2,0] } <$passwd>;
};

open my $ps, "-|", "ps", "aux" or die "Can't open ps command: $!";

while(<$ps>) {
  my @cols = split ' ', $_, 11;
  $cols[0] = $id_2_name{$cols[0]} unless $cols[0] =~ /[^0-9]/;
  print join " ", @cols if $cols[0] eq $username;
}
```

Comment: Amon, thank you, however, I keep getting 'ps' is not recongized as an internal or externla command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: @JeffreyLocke What OS are you on? I tested my script under Ubuntu GNU/Linux; it works fine. Windows does not have `ps`. Neither does Windows have `/etc/passwords` … You can't develop programs for Unix or Unix-like systems under Windows (except with the Cygwin layer).

Comment: I am in Network Programming Class. They are making us use Perl.